# How to find the attached devices UUID through terminal?

Tags: command-line

Is there any other method  to find all the attached  devices UUID  through terminal(other than using the `blkid`command ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, list devices by entering:

```
ll /dev/disk/by-uuid
```

[image: screenshot]

By default, `ll` is an alias of `ls -alF`.

Answer (score 24):

the best way I found for this is:

```
sudo blkid
```

for example the output of a specific USB in my Ubuntu is:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="16GB" UUID="25495C984912BBC3" TYPE="ntfs"
```

Comment: Oddly this comes up empty if you've just installed formatted and mounted a new drive.

Comment: Except that the OP asked "other than using the blkid command"

Answer (score 4):

You can look in `/dev/disk/by-uuid/`. These files are symlinks to the `/dev/...` device. For example, my dmraid RAID0 disk (which makes up my root partition is `/dev/dm-1` so the following gets its UUID:

```
$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid | grep dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 21 21:07 1b66bb9e-5b02-49f1-8cf9-bc3f649d70a6 -> ../../dm-1
```

Comment: the above command doesn't display anything.

Comment: I think there is not dm-1 in our case, "ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid" works alone but "ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid | grep dm-1"  did nothing.

Comment: Exactly. As I explained in the answer, in my case my root device is `/dev/dm-1`. In your case it could be `/dev/sda1`, or something like that.