# Does Ubuntu have a "device manager" equivalent for USB drives?

Tags: hard-drive

I just started with Ubuntu and I am learning how to use it properly. I am a bit confused however about 2 things.

Firstly,
Is there a "device manager"(windows) equivalent in Ubuntu? How can I see what devices are seen by the system + drivers installed?

Secondly,
I noticed that Ubuntu doesn't use C:\ or D:\ drive, how would I select hard drive without the letters? I see that USB drives are in /media/(LONG STRING), is there an easier way to access USB drive or other hard drives?

I put in reasonable effort to learn as much as I can with the use of documentation provided, but those 2 things kind of confuse me at this point and I was wondering if someone could clarify this.

Thanks :)

Comment: 1). disk, 2) for accessing USB you need to be a bit more explicit. Welcome to AskUbuntu...

Comment: Device Manager: Try 'lsusb' and 'lspci'. Do you have hardware that you believe is not being detected?

Comment: lspci works great. It confirmed that my USB 3.0 control is indeed connected to the PCI and is recognized, but when I plug a USB device into it, it doesn't show in "my computer". How do I update the drivers or how do I even view the drivers currently installed?

Comment: USB storage devices and HDDs should appear in the left side panel of the file browser. They are usually identifiable by size and partition labels, as well as [UUIDs](http://askubuntu.com/questions/386536/how-to-find-the-attached-devices-uuid-through-terminal). To see the drivers that are currently in use, run `lspci -nnk`, or use hardinfo program from the repositories. Updating drivers is rarely necessary, and is rather difficult.

Comment: gnome-disks shows all devices attached to your system as well as options to detach them safely. and if you use a file browser the equivalent of C;\ on windows is your /home/<username> folder

Answer (score 75, accepted):

When I googled "Linux device manager equivalent" one of the recommendations is `hardinfo` which I already had installed but which you can install with:

```
sudo apt install hardinfo
```

Then typing `hardinfo` in the terminal or calling from Dash (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) the gui appears like this:

[image: hardinfo]

The comments above suggest using `lspci` and `lsusb` which are what I use most often but your question asks for a Windows "device manager" equivalent.

Comment: I wasn't able to install this, the apt package wasn't found on ubuntu 17

Comment: @Jonathan727 Sorry I'm not running 17.04. It appears to be available in 17.04 from the Ubuntu folks though: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/zesty/+package/hardinfo

Comment: Hello @WinEunuuchs2Unix, is it possible to disable a device by using the GUI which appears when I run hardinfo? I tried to do that, but I didn't see the option disable.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Sorry for late reply. A `udev` rule can disable a device: See this: [how to disable USB devices based on vendor id in Linux environment? ](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/63199/200094 "Reply to comment by Ask Ubuntu user: https://askubuntu.com/users/994823/gennaro-arguzzi")