# What is the best way to know if AMD graphic card is installed?

Tags: 64-bit, radeon, amd-graphics

How to get sure that my AMD graphic card is installed in ubuntu?is there anything similar to device manager in windows?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/887264/does-ubuntu-have-a-device-manager-equivalent-and-what-is-an-easy-way-to-acces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the `lshw -class display` command and it will tell you what vendor you are using for your gpu. If you don't have `lshw` you can install it with `apt install lshw`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lspci` to list the devices.

Adding -v or -vv (or more v's) gives you more detail.

For usb there is also `lsusb` or `lsblk` for block-devices...