# Ubuntu 20.04 VM on VirtualBox incompatible with "hardinfo" app

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, ubuntu-gnome

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 VM on Oracle VirtualBox 7.0 (from Win10 host OS), and would like to see the HW elements via some GUI app (not from command line). From this Q: [Does Ubuntu have a "device manager" equivalent? And what is an easy way to access USB drives?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/887264/does-ubuntu-have-a-device-manager-equivalent-and-what-is-an-easy-way-to-acces)
I understood what the best option is "hardinfo" app (System Profiler and Benchmark).

Unfortunately, after installing (both via command line and via Ubuntu Software App) it looks like the **hardinfo app has some graphic issues/incompatibility** (snapshot below)

I'd very appreciate the tip how to overcome this issue, since I'm very interesting to get HW info in the GUI manner.

Note: I haven't any issue with other GUI apps

Snapshot:
[image: Graphic issue:]

Hardinfo app version:
[image]

Full version of Ubuntu and Gnome:
[image]

Thanks
Andrey

Comment: Installing VirtualBox Extension Packs  https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#intro-installing

Comment: Thanks, Johan. VitrualBox already have the Extension Pack (VirtualBox 7.0.4 Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack) installed.

Comment: A virtual machine won't show you hardware.

Comment: @Pilot6, but isn't this "hardinfo" app is just a graphical representation of text which returns from misc CLI commands, like "lshw"? If VirtualBox hypervisor didn't emulate HW, commands like "lshw" should return some empty lists of HW, and I'd expect what "Hardinfo" itself should represent empty HW, but its graphic itself should work OK (at list title of window)?